# React event listeners based on changes in state made with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Good afternoon,

I am having some difficulty working with React and Redux when I am trying to redirect users of my app based on changes in state.

At a high level: I want my app's route to change when my `user` object in state is populated with information from home `/` to `/student/:username`.

Right now I have accomplished this in a hacky sort of fashion.

In my `Login` component I use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to listen and dispatch an action when an access token from a 3rd party API is passed back to the client from my Express server.

```
import React from "react";

import LoginForm from "../minor/LoginForm";

const Login = React.createClass({

  componentDidUpdate(){
    const {success, access_token} = this.props.loginStatus;

    if (success === true && access_token !== null){
      console.log("It worked getting your data now...");
      this.props.getUserData(access_token);
    } else if (success === false || access_token === null){
      console.log("Something went wrong...");
    } 

  }, 
render(){

    return(

        <div className="loginComponentWrapper">
          <h1>Slots</h1>
          <LoginForm loginSubmit={this.props.loginSubmit}
                     router={this.props.router}
                     user={this.props.user} />
          <a href="/register">New User?</a>
        </div>
      )
  }
});
```

Notice that I am passing `router` and `user` to my `LoginForm` component. I do this in order to use ANOTHER `componentDidUpdate` where I use the `.push` method on `router` like so:

```
import React from "react";

const LoginForm = React.createClass({


  componentDidUpdate(){
    const {router, user} = this.props;

    if (user.username !== null){
       router.push(`/student/${user.username}`);
    }
  },


  render(){

      return(
        <div className="loginWrapper">
          <div className="loginBox">
            <form className="loginForm" action="">
              <input ref={(input) => this.username_field = input} type="text" placeholder="username" defaultValue="kitties@kit.com" />
              <input ref={(input) => this.password_field = input} type="text" placeholder="password" defaultValue="meowMeow3" />
              <button onClick={this.loginAttempt}>Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
  }

});
```

Sure it works but I'm certain this is a overly complicated solution and not what is considered a best practice. I've tried adding a custom listener method within my `Login` component but I've never had it successfully fire off, instead my app gets stuck in a loop.

Is there a way I can do this using Redux and keep my components tidier, or take advantage of `componentDidUpdate` in a more efficient way?

As always I'd appreciate some more experienced eyes on my issue and look forward to some feedback!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

`App.js`

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreators from "../actions/userActions.js";

import StoreShell from "./StoreShell.js";

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    loginStatus: state.loginStatus,
    user: state.user
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoreShell);

export default App;
```

This component "sprinkles" all my redux stuff and state data into my container component named `StoreShell` that in turn passes all that data to props for the elements that make up the UI like `Login` and `LoginForm` am I taking  too many steps?

`StoreShell.js`

```
import React from "react";

const StoreShell = React.createClass({

    render(){

        return(

            <div className="theBigWrapper">
              {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
            </div>

          )

    }
})

export default StoreShell;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that could make the login flow easier to manage and reason about and tidy up your components a bit.  First a few general points:

I'm not certain why you have divided login logic between the two components?  The idiomatic React/Redux approach would be to have a container component that deals with logic, and a presentation component that deals with presentation.  Currently both components do a little bit of each.

You don't need to pass `props.router` up and down through your components.  React router provides a HOC that provides router as a props called withRouter( [docs here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options)).  You just wrap a component in withRouter and props.router is available - everything else stays the same.

```
export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

My personal feeling is that the URI is part of your app's state, and as such it should be maintained within the store and updated by dispatching actions.  There is a cracking library available to do this - [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).  Once you have it setup then you can pass the `push` method to your components (or elsewhere... see the next points) to navigate:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const NavigatingComponent = props => (
    <button onClick={() => props.push('/page')}>Navigate</button>
);

const mapStateToProps = null;
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    push
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavigatingComponent);
```

One of the great things about having the URI in our store is that we don't need access to `props.router` to change location, which opens the avenue of moving the login logic outside of our components.  There are several ways we can do this, the simplest is probably [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), which allows our action creators to return functions instead of objects.  We could then write our component to simply call a `login` function with username and password entered, and our thunk takes care of the rest:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

// action creators....
const loginStarted = () => ({
    type: 'LOGIN_STARTED'
)};

const loginFailed = (error) => ({
    type: 'LOGIN_FAILED',
    payload: {
       error
    }
};

const loginSucceeded = (user) => ({
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCEEDED',
    payload: {
       user
    }
};

const getUserData = (access_token) => (dispatch) => {
    Api.getUserData(access_token) // however you get user data
    .then(response => {
        dispatch(loginSucceeded(response.user));
        dispatch(push(`/student/${response.user.username}`));
    });

export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginStarted());

    Api.login({ username, password }) // however you call your backend
    .then(response => {
        if (response.success && response.access_token) {
            getUserData(access_token)(dispatch);
        } else {
            dispatch(loginFailed(response.error));
        }
    });
}
```

The only thing your components do is call the initial login function, which could be implemented something like:

Container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { login } from '../path/to/actionCreators';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

const LoginContainer = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit() {
        this.props.login(
           this.usernameInput.value,
           this.passwordInput.value
        );
    },

    setUsernameRef(input) {
        this.usernameInput = input;
    },

    setPasswordRef(input) {
        this.passwordInput = input;
    },

    render() {
        return (
           <LoginForm
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
              setUsernameRef={this.setUsernameRef.bind(this)}
              setPasswordRef={this.setPasswordRef.bind(this)}
           />
        );
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = null;
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export const LoginForm = ({ handleSubmit, setUsernameRef, setPasswordRef }) => (  
    <div className="loginWrapper">
        <div className="loginBox">
            <form className="loginForm" action="">
                <input ref={setUsernameRef} type="text" placeholder="username" defaultValue="kitties@kit.com" />
                <input ref={setPasswordRef} type="text" placeholder="password" defaultValue="meowMeow3" />
                <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

This has achieved separation of a logic/data providing container, and a stateless presentational component.  The LoginForm component can be written simply as a function above because it has no responsibility to deal with logic.  The container is also a very simple component - the logic has all been isolated in our action creator/thunk and is much easier to read and reason about.

`redux-thunk` is just one way of managing asynchronous side effects with redux - there are many others with different approaches.  My personal preference is toward [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), which may be interesting for you to look at.  In my own redux journey, however, I certainly benefited from using and understanding `redux-thunk` first before finding it's limitations/drawbacks and moving on, and would suggest this route to others.

Comment: Truly I've just started adopting redux and I appreciate your response because I think I understand the purpose of redux a bit better. I like URI as a part of state and I think that's a smart practice. I have experience using `redux-thunk` in this project and will expand my use now. There is a lot of great stuff here and I appreciate your thorough response. One question: Why is `connect` used at the bottom of the `Login` component along with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`? I do this in another container component "above" `Login`. I'll update my question to show you.

Comment: I `connect`ed the LoginContainer because to me that is the best place to do so.  While it is possible to pass the login actioncreator as a prop from a connected component higher up the tree, this just adds needless complexity to me.  It also harms the ease of re-usability of your components.  I.e. When LoginContainer is connected. if you want to place another login component elsewhere in your site, then all you need to do is import it and render it.  If a parent component is responsible for `connect`, then every time you want to re-use it you will have to connect its parent.

Comment: This makes sense to me because my components become polluted with lots of props and dispatchers for example `Login` which is my container for `LoginForm` is one such. Based on this discussion it seems like I can get rid of my `App.js` component above, no?

Comment: Yes the app component's connects become unnecessary when you import and connect the pieces you need on a per-component level.  This is how many React/Redux applications are structured - each container imports the action creators they need for mapDispatchToProps, and the state they need using selectors (take a look at the reselect library) for mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **`react-router` version 4.x.x**: You can just render a `Redirect` component that handles the redirection for you (see [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/auth-workflow) in react-router docs).

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

import LoginForm from "../minor/LoginForm";

const Login = React.createClass({

  componentDidUpdate(){
    const {success, access_token} = this.props.loginStatus;

    if (success === true && access_token !== null){
      console.log("It worked getting your data now...");
      this.props.getUserData(access_token);
    } else if (success === false || access_token === null){
      console.log("Something went wrong...");
    } 

  }

  render(){
    // if user is defined, redirect to /student/:username
    if (this.props.user.username !== null) {
      return (<Redirect to={ `/student/${this.props.user.username}` } />)
    }

    // otherwise render the login form
    return(
      <div className="loginComponentWrapper">
        <h1>Slots</h1>
        <LoginForm loginSubmit={this.props.loginSubmit}
                   router={this.props.router}
                   user={this.props.user} />
        <a href="/register">New User?</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

If you're using **`react-router` version 3.x.x**: The the way you're doing it is mostly correct. I would move the redirect from the `LoginForm` component to `Login` component; that way `LoginForm` does not need to depend on the `user` prop.

I know, I don't like the pattern much either.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware that `react-router` 4.x.x was available! I'm going to have to look into it and see how it can benefit my project. I appreciate your answer because I can see the solution in my own code. It turns out that I'm using `react-router` 3.0.1 maybe it's time to update...